# How to send().await in a channel inside a tokio::spawn task?

Tags: rust, async-await, channel, rust-tokio

The below code is very simple. I'm wondering how Rust people fixed this channels/spawn/mutex/async/await issue.

The issue is within `broadcast()` function. I'm getting the error below and I know the reason: `clients.lock()` is not usable here because of https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/shared-state#holding-a-mutexguard-across-an-await.

How to `send().await` and at the same time do this waiting in a `spawn`ed task?

I need to do this in a `spawn` task because I need to not wait at all when calling the `broadcast()` function from my handlers.

I know I can https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/shared-state#use-tokios-asynchronous-mutex but they also say:

> an asynchronous mutex is more expensive than an ordinary mutex, and it is typically better to use one of the two other approaches.

For this reason I'm wondering if there is a better way I don't see yet.

**Is there a better way than this shared state method?**

REPL: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/pk8weh

```rust
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

type TeamId = String;
type PlayerId = String;

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Broadcaster {
    clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<TeamId, HashMap<PlayerId, Vec<Connection>>>>>,
}

pub struct Connection {
    pub session_id: String,
    pub player_id: String,
    pub sender: mpsc::Sender<Arc<Message>>,
}

pub struct Message {
    pub team_id: TeamId,
    pub session_id: String,
    pub message: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let broadcaster = Arc::new(Broadcaster::default());

    for i in 0..10 {
        let broadcaster = broadcaster.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut rx = broadcaster
                .add_client("1", &format!("session_{i}"), &format!("player_{i}"))
                .await;

            while let Some(_) = rx.recv().await {
                println!("GOT message in team 1 - i: {i}");
            }
        });

        println!("added team 1 - client {}", i);
    }

    for i in 0..5 {
        let broadcaster = broadcaster.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut rx = broadcaster
                .add_client("2", &format!("session_{i}"), &format!("player_{i}"))
                .await;

            while let Some(_) = rx.recv().await {
                println!("GOT message in team 2 - i: {i}");
            }
        });

        println!("added team 2 - client {}", i);
    }

    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100)).await;

    dbg!(broadcaster.clients.lock().unwrap().len());

    for _ in 0..50 {
        broadcaster
            .broadcast(Message {
                team_id: "1".to_string(),
                session_id: "1".to_string(),
                message: "fake one".to_string(),
            })
            .await;
    }
}

impl Broadcaster {
    pub async fn add_client(
        &self,
        team_id: &str,
        session_id: &str,
        player_id: &str,
    ) -> mpsc::Receiver<Arc<Message>> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Arc<Message>>(10);

        let mut clients = self.clients.lock().unwrap();

        if !clients.contains_key(team_id) {
            clients.insert(team_id.to_string(), HashMap::new());
        }

        let players = clients.get_mut(team_id).unwrap();

        if !players.contains_key(player_id) {
            players.insert(player_id.to_string().into(), Vec::new());
        }

        let connections = players.get_mut(player_id).unwrap();

        let connection = Connection {
            session_id: session_id.to_string(),
            player_id: player_id.to_string(),
            sender: tx,
        };

        connections.push(connection);

        rx
    }

    // HERE THE ISSUE!

    pub async fn broadcast(&self, message: Message) {
        let clients = self.clients.clone();

        let message = Arc::new(message);

        // I need this to not wait for broadcast()

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let clients = clients.lock().unwrap();

            for connections in clients.get(&message.team_id).unwrap().values() {
                for connection in connections {
                    connection.sender.send(message.clone()).await;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should keep reading through that first link and use `tokio::sync::Mutex` instead of `std::sync::Mutex`. Or clone your `senders` and release the lock before sending to them. And the issue isn't with `spawn`, you'd have the same error without it.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. I know `tokio::Mutex` but I'm wondering if there is another approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have redesigned your approach a little bit, first of all, let's use the already provided by `tokio` broadcast channel.

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Broadcaster {
    sender: broadcast::Sender<Arc<Message>>,
}
```

Let's move the filtering logic to the end receiver. Let's call it `Listener`.

```
pub struct Listener {
    // Could be added more fields to filter the exact receiver more precisely
    session_id: String,
    team_id: String,
    receiver: broadcast::Receiver<Arc<Message>>,
}
```

The listener will have a single API.

```
impl Listener {
    async fn recv(&mut self) -> Option<Arc<Message>> {
        match self.receiver.recv().await {
            Ok(msg) if msg.team_id == self.team_id && msg.session_id == self.session_id => {
                Some(msg)
            }
            // need to handle RecvError::Closed,
            Err(_) | Ok(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, here we receive the message and then check if this message should be processed by our listener.

Then simple implementation of `Broadcaster`

```
impl Broadcaster {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let (sender, _rx) = broadcast::channel::<Arc<Message>>(100);

        Self { sender }
    }

    pub async fn add_client(&self, team_id: &str, session_id: &str, _player_id: &str) -> Listener {
        Listener {
            session_id: session_id.to_owned(),
            team_id: team_id.to_owned(),
            receiver: self.sender.subscribe(),
        }
    }

    pub async fn broadcast(&self, message: Message) {
        let message = Arc::new(message);
        // non-blocking operation.
        // you need to handle the result
        let _ = self.sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Full code with main:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::broadcast;

type TeamId = String;
type PlayerId = String;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Broadcaster {
    sender: broadcast::Sender<Arc<Message>>,
}

pub struct Connection {
    pub session_id: String,
    pub player_id: String,
    pub sender: broadcast::Sender<Arc<Message>>,
}

pub struct Message {
    pub team_id: TeamId,
    pub session_id: String,
    pub message: String,
}

pub struct Listener {
    session_id: String,
    team_id: String,
    receiver: broadcast::Receiver<Arc<Message>>,
}

impl Listener {
    async fn recv(&mut self) -> Option<Arc<Message>> {
        match self.receiver.recv().await {
            Ok(msg) if msg.team_id == self.team_id && msg.session_id == self.session_id => {
                Some(msg)
            }
            // need to handle RecvError::Closed,
            Err(_) | Ok(_) => None,
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let broadcaster = Broadcaster::new();

    for i in 0..10 {
        let broadcaster = broadcaster.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut rx = broadcaster
                .add_client("1", &format!("1"), &format!("player_{i}"))
                .await;

            while let Some(_) = rx.recv().await {
                println!("GOT message in team 1 - i: {i}");
            }
        });

        println!("added team 1 - client {}", i);
    }

    for i in 0..5 {
        let broadcaster = broadcaster.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut rx = broadcaster
                .add_client("2", &format!("session_{i}"), &format!("player_{i}"))
                .await;

            while let Some(_) = rx.recv().await {
                println!("GOT message in team 2 - i: {i}");
            }
        });

        println!("added team 2 - client {}", i);
    }

    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(100)).await;

    dbg!(broadcaster.sender.receiver_count());

    for _ in 0..50 {
        broadcaster
            .broadcast(Message {
                team_id: "1".to_string(),
                session_id: "1".to_string(),
                message: "fake one".to_string(),
            })
            .await;
    }
}

impl Broadcaster {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let (sender, _rx) = broadcast::channel::<Arc<Message>>(100);

        Self { sender }
    }

    pub async fn add_client(&self, team_id: &str, session_id: &str, _player_id: &str) -> Listener {
        Listener {
            session_id: session_id.to_owned(),
            team_id: team_id.to_owned(),
            receiver: self.sender.subscribe(),
        }
    }

    pub async fn broadcast(&self, message: Message) {
        let message = Arc::new(message);
        // you need to handle the result
        let _ = self.sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought of this solution but since I will have tens of thousands of listeners grouped by team_id I thought the hashmap would speed up because I only select those from that team.  But now thinking about it, I can use the same system you proposed with a hashmap, what do you think?

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code with your idea, that includes HashMap?

Comment: I don't have the code yet. I'm still thinking but maybe it's impossible.

Comment: Do you mean to have a hash map with senders for each team_id?

Comment: Yeah. Something like that. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, why not? But I think this solution will be slower. This needs to be investigated.
Here is what I have https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=387a47561e0b6ce48e390db36cdb91b3

Also, I think that it would be better for performance if we replaced the default HashMap with a lock-free implementation https://github.com/wvwwvwwv/scalable-concurrent-containers/

Comment: I'm scared about using something not std. I don't understand how can be this hashmap used without Mutex?

Comment: It's lock-free collections, I am not so smart to explain it in simple words. Here is some kind of tutorial about this topic https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Bw8-vvtA-E8

Comment: Lock-free collections are not always faster. You need to benchmark with your use-case to be sure.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman what do you think about this solution using broadcast instead of an mpsc for each connection? And what about grouping by team_id in an HashMap?

Comment: @Silvestr is there a way to transform the `while let Some(_) = rx.recv().await { println!("GOT message in team 2 - i: {i}"); }` to a stream? I need to create a stream for `axum::sse::Sse::new()`.

Comment: Yeah, it’s possible. You just need to wrap it with https://crates.io/crates/async-stream, and then put it into sse

Comment: I'm using this:

`res = async_stream::stream! {
    loop {
        if let Some(msg) = rx.recv().await {
            yield Ok(sse::Event::default().data(msg));
        }
    }
};` What do you think?

Comment: I need more context, but for me seems like the right way to use the streams.

Comment: Is that `loop` correct? Should I use it like this? This is my doubt. I'm scared that is always doing something. But maybe it only is "monitoring" the `rx.recv().await` right?

Comment: Maybe something like this will be better => https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f020523bab0582be79b26586cf569fc5

Comment: I tried you suggestion but the sse connection after one message or two is closed from the server. Maybe the `loop` is necessary here, what you think? Is the `while let...` finished after a message come in?

Comment: @FredHors I just prepared the small example with axum for you. You could test it with a browser. Please take a look. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b6fe75b2f9ce8058a8afd02faf756e1 Basically sse subscribes for events, and events push 100 messages. You need to open in a separate tab sse endpoint and then open events. Then on previous tabs you will see the results.

Comment: @Silvestr, you're very kind! Thanks! I re-created my issue: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b92e97bf4a8d299c64bbe7f4bfdd49b7. The issue is on line 87. If I return `None` the `stream!` is closed. This is the issue "I fixed" with `loop` but I don't like it. What do you think?

Comment: The `index.html` file I'm using in `assets` dir is: `<script type="text/javascript">
    var eventSource = new EventSource('sse?1');

    eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('Message from server:', event.data);
    }
</script>`

Comment: You need to use the Result here => custom_receive